# LinkedIn API v2 - How to get permission to request recommended jobs?

Tags: linkedin-api

The LinkedIn API [claims to provide information about recommended jobs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/jobs/recommended-jobs). They say you need to use the permission "r_JYMBII" to do so. I'm able to request other information like basic profile info using other permissions. But how do I go about getting permission to request recommended jobs? I read somewhere you might need to apply for a partner program or something, but then when I followed those links they said the partner program is no longer happening. What am I missing?